# palindrome sub-string of the size given by user from string given by user in asp.net web pages

Tags: asp.net, web

A palindrome is a word or phrase that reads the same backwards as forwards. Some common
examples are "Mom", "Dad", and “Bob" or even the sentence "Madam, I'm Adam." When
determining a palindrome, the case of letters is ignored, as is any spacing or punctuation if the
phrase happens to be a sentence. You need to create a web page having two text boxes and a
button. User will enter any string in text box and size of palindrome that he wants to search in the
string. After button press, you need to find all sub-strings of the given size, which are palindrome by
using AJAX and inform the user about the result. If no palindrome sub-string of the given size is
found, inform the user with a message.
You need to use button outside update panel with a trigger and update progress control as well.

```
Thread.Sleep(2000); 
string inputstring = TextBox1.Text; 
string s = TextBox1.Text.ToString(); 
string str = string.Empty; 
for (int j = s.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
{ 
    str = str + s[j]; 
} 
//for(String i=TextBox2.Text;i=str.Length) 
if (s == str) 
{ 
    Label1.Text = s + " is palindrom"; 
} 
else 
{
    Label1.Text = s + " is not palindrom"; 
}
```

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avPBY.png)

Comment: Thread.Sleep(2000);
            string inputstring = TextBox1.Text;
            string s = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
            string str = string.Empty;
            for (int j = s.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                
                str = str + s[j];
            }
            
           //for(String i=TextBox2.Text;i=str.Length)
            if (s == str)
            {
                Label1.Text = s + " is palindrom";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = s + " is not palindrom";
            }

Comment: this is code i am working on but can't find my real problem solution

Comment: Hi @gulsher, welcome to SO. Please avoid posting images of your code. I noticed you pasted it as a comment so I formatted it and moved it into the question for you. Please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: ok sir thanks i m new so don't knw

Comment: @gusher No worries. The one thing I should mention is StackOverflow is not a homework writing service. You must show what you have tried for people to help out. Enjoy the site!